# How to grok catalina log file

Tags: date, tomcat, logstash, logstash-grok, catalina.out

I'm trying to find a pattern for this line of log (extracted from catalina.log) of an apache tomcat 8 installation.

`30-Apr-2019 15:40:40.044 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log message`

No one of the date pattern include in logstash matches with this date format.

Do you have idea how can I parse this date `30-Apr-2019 15:40:40.044` to a timestamp in my logstash filter ?

Thanks

Comment: `%{MONTHDAY}-%{MONTH}-%{YEAR} %{HOUR}:?%{MINUTE}(?::?%{SECOND})` You'll have to put that in a custom pattern file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated by @baudsp, you may add the date pattern for catalina using a custom pattern file, or use it embedded in the grok, as shown [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html#_custom_patterns)

```
(?<date>%{MONTHDAY}-%{MONTH}-%{YEAR} %{HOUR}:?%{MINUTE}(?::?%{SECOND}))
```

If you use the pattern often, put it in a file would probably be better, and provide more readability

Answer (score 0):

Finally, there is a solution :

I put a new pattern in a file custom.txt

```
MY_DATE_PATTERN %{MONTHDAY}-%{MONTH}-%{YEAR} %{HOUR}:?%{MINUTE}(?::?%{SECOND})
```

Then in my logstash.conf I put this filter :

```
grok {
      patterns_dir => ["./patterns"]
      match => {
        "message" => "%{MY_DATE_PATTERN:timestamp}%{SPACE}%{GREEDYDATA:loglevel}%{SPACE}\[%{GREEDYDATA:thread}\]%{SPACE}%{JAVACLASS:classname}%{SPACE}%{GREEDYDATA:logmessage}"
      }
    }
    date {
      match => [ "timestamp" , "dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS" ]
    }
```

Thanks for your help